Why is my custom package not found with Mathematica 14.1?
I wanted to load my custom packages using 14.1, but the packages cannot be loaded, and I get the error message:

"Cannot open MyPackage`.

What can I do?

With Mathematica 14.1 now called Wolfram 14.1 the application directory has moved, as explained in the documentation: Upgrading from Mathematica to Wolfram.
Fortunately (of course you have a backup) the packages are still in the old directory folders.
The new place for your packages on Windows is now:

C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\Wolfram\Applications

and the old place was:

C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\Applications

Just move your files from the old to the new directory.

Hi Domen thanks for the link to the file!

https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/MigrateSettingsToWolframApp/
